# XSS Vulnerability

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, xss

I am developing a mobile application using jquery mobile. I want to eliminate all the xss attack in my app. When I was testing my application Cross site reflected error occurs. Actually, the error occurs in my query. Is there any javascript code to eliminate all the Xss errors? Or else give me an idea to eliminate those errors both in the client and server side?

Thanks in advance!

---

Thanks for your prompt response.

Query:

SELECT%20Id%2C%20Name%2C%20lsc_*Course*_r.Name%2C%20lsc_*StartDate*_c%2C%20lsc_*Venue*_r.Name%20FROM%20lsc_*event*_c%20WHERE%20lsc_*StartDate*_c%20%3E%3D%20TODAY%20ORDER%20BY%20lsc_*StartDate*_c   72aaaalert(1)606c8b0c254

&_=1342613913758 HTTP/1.1

I got this  / 72aaaalert(1)606c8b0c254 / error at the end of the query. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any javascript code to eliminate all the Xss errors?

No. There is no way to magically fix all XSS problems.

You must encode data before using it. If you accept text input, then you must convert it to SQL before inserting it into a database, and into HTML before inserting it into HTML and so on. (Otherwise the text might include characters with special meaning in SQL / HTML / etc).